# The limit of $\sin \lfloor x\rfloor/\lfloor x\rfloor$ as $x\to 0$

Tags: calculus, limits, functions

If

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}\dfrac{\sin \lfloor x\rfloor}{\lfloor x\rfloor} &, \lfloor x \rfloor \neq 0 \\
\quad 0 &, \lfloor x\rfloor = 0. \end{cases}$$

Find limit of $f(x)$ when $x$ tends to $0$.

My answer is that it doesn't exist because the left hand limit is $\sin 1$ whereas the right hand limit comes out to be zero.

Comment: You should check your limits again.

Comment: is $[x]$ the greatest integer function?

Comment: I've interpreted `[x]` as the greatest integer (aka floor) function. If that was not what you meant, please correct.

Comment: You can disregard my comment if you are using the greatest integer function. Then you are right.

Comment: If $x_n\to0$ ($x_n>0$) then  $x_n<1$ for $n > N_0$, and $\lfloor x_n\rfloor = 0$, $f(x_n) = 0$; if $x_n < 0$, analogously $\lfloor x_n\rfloor = -1$, and $f(x_n)=\sin 1$. So you are completely right

Comment: I did mean the greatest integer function.  Am i correct?

Comment: How or why, @egreg ?

Comment: @egreg when [x] = 0, f(x) is defined as 0.   Note: [x] refers to greatest integer function of x.

Comment: @kay Sorry, I misread the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\left \lfloor {x} \right \rfloor$ is the integer part, then for $0 \le x <1$ you have $\left \lfloor {x} \right \rfloor = 0$, so the limit towards $0^+$ is $0$ by the definition of $f$. For $-1 \le x < 0$ you have $\left \lfloor {x} \right \rfloor = -1$ so the limit towards $0^-$ is the limit of $\frac {\sin (-1)} {-1} = \sin 1$. Therefore, $f$ has no limit in $0$.